# How to increase padding displayed items combobox?

Tags: wpf, xaml, templates, combobox, itemscontrol

I want to write XAML template of a combobox to increase the spaces/padding between items.
I searched for this but almost end up with the ItemsPresenter:

```
<ItemsPresenter x:Name="ItemsPresenter"
                KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Contained"
                SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
```

How can I format the item (border, padding, font...) using this template? 
Please help.

Comment: I'm in the need of this too! Looking forward to hear from all of you guys.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use [ItemContainerStyle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemcontainerstyle.aspx) to apply a style to the [ComboBoxItems](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.comboboxitem.aspx) that sets properties such as padding:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding}">
    <ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="5"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Blue"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2"/>
            <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Courier New"/>
        </Style>
    </ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ComboBox>
```

If you want it to apply to all combo boxes, you could instead create an implicit style for ComboBoxItem in your Resources:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="5"/>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<StackPanel>
    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding}"/>
    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding}"/>
</StackPanel>
```